# chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) ) isn't working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want x to increase each time a new tab opens. Why isn't it working?

```
    var x = 0;
    function increase(){
        x++;
   }
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
            increase();
    });
```

Comment: Just checking that you have added the "tabs" permission to your manifest.json file?

If you add a `console.log("test")` or something to your listenter, does that print in the console?

Comment: I do have the tabs permission. How do I check to see if it has printed?

Comment: Are you using chrome or firefox, also is this code in a background script or a content-script?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it is in a content-script

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `tabs` api cannot be used within a content script (check out the docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for what can and can't).

In order to achieve what your trying to do, you need to place your tab counting code in the background script. If you need access to the variable `x` within your content script you'll have to pass the data between your background and content scripts using [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).

For example you could setup your background script to increase `x` whenever a new tab is opened, then whenever your content script needed this value it could ask the background script for it:

Background.js:

```
var x = 0;

function increase(){
  x++;
}

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
  increase();
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "tabCount")
      sendResponse({count: x});
  });
```

Content-Script.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "tabCount"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.count);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! However, it works when I use a listener such as chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tab) but not for chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener. Is there anything specific for the onUpdated listener?

Comment: That's interesting as according to the google docs, the tabs api should be forbidden in content scripts. There might be an exception that the OnUpdated event is allowd to fire in a content script for updates that happen relating to the tab the content script is associated with, but this is just speculation.

Comment: The message passing isn't working, and the variable just immediate passes between background and content without message passing